# Why am I getting a divide by zero error here?

Tags: python, pytorch

So I'm following along this [tutorial in the docs](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html) on custom datasets. I'm using the MNIST dataset instead of the fancy one in the tutorial. This is the extension of the `Dataset` class I wrote:

```
class KaggleMNIST(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, csv_file, transform=None):
        self.pixel_frame = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.pixel_frame)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if torch.is_tensor(index):
            index = index.tolist()

        image = self.pixel_frame.iloc[index, 1:]
        image = np.array([image])

        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)

        return image
```

It works, until I try to use a transform on it:

```
tsf = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(), 
                          transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,))
                         ])
                          
trainset = KaggleMNIST('train/train.csv', transform=tsf)

image0 = trainset[0]
```

I've looked at the stack trace, and it seems like the normalization is happening in this line of code:

```
c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\torchvision\transforms\functional.py in normalize(tensor, mean, std, inplace)
--> 218     tensor.sub_(mean[:, None, None]).div_(std[:, None, None])
```

So I don't get why there is divide by zero since `std` should be 0.5, nowhere remotely close to a small value.

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT:**

This does not answer my question, but I discovered that if I change these lines of code:

```
image = self.pixel_frame.iloc[index, 1:] 
image = np.array([image])
```

to

```
image = self.pixel_frame.iloc[index, 1:].to_numpy(dtype='float64').reshape(1, -1)
```

Essentially, making sure the datatype was `float64` fixed the problem. I'm still not sure why the problem existed in the first place, so I'd still be happy for a well-explained answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `dtype` of the data read is `int64`

```
img = np.array([pixel_frame.iloc[0, 1:]])
img.dtype
# output
dtype('int64')
```

This forces the mean and std to be converted to `int64` and as std is 0.5, it becomes 0, and raises the following error:

```
>>> tsf(img)
ValueError: std evaluated to zero after conversion to torch.int64, leading to division by zero.
```

It's because the mean and std are converted to `dtype` of the dataset during normalization.

```
def normalize(tensor, mean, std, inplace=False):
    ...
    dtype = tensor.dtype
    mean = torch.as_tensor(mean, dtype=dtype, device=tensor.device)
    std = torch.as_tensor(std, dtype=dtype, device=tensor.device)
    if (std == 0).any():
        raise ValueError('std evaluated to zero after conversion to {}, leading to division by zero.'.format(dtype))
```

That's why converting the dtype to `float` fixes the error.