# Pytorch, torchvision.transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0,5), (0.5, 0.5, 0,5)) used on kaggle anime face data gives value error because of zero std

Tags: pytorch, kaggle, torchvision

```
dir = './animefacedataset'        
imagesize = 68
batchsize = 128
RGB_mean_std_minusonetoonerange = ((0.5, 0.5, 0,5), (0.5, 0.5, 0,5))   `*#same for (0.5, 0.5, 0,5), (0.5, 0.5, 0,5)*`
augmented_normalized_tensorized = T.Compose([T.Resize(imagesize), 
                                             T.CenterCrop(imagesize), 
                                             T.ToTensor(), 
                                          T.Normalize(*RGB_mean_std_minusonetoonerange)])
traindataset = ImageFolder(dir, augmented_normalized_tensorized)        
**image, _ = traindataset[0]**
```

This last line raises valueerror:

> ```
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchvision/transforms/functional.py in normalize(tensor, mean, std, in place)
>     344     std = torch.as_tensor(std, dtype=dtype, device=tensor.device)
>     345     if (std == 0).any():
> --> 346         raise ValueError('std evaluated to zero after conversion to {}, leading to division by zero.'.format(dtype))
>     347     if mean.ndim == 1:
>     348         mean = mean.view(-1, 1, 1)
>
> ValueError: std evaluated to zero after conversion to torch.float32, leading to division by zero.
> ```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting a divide by zero error here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62559389/why-am-i-getting-a-divide-by-zero-error-here)

Comment: I did not create any custom dataset as shown above, I just used ImageFolder which should work on jpg's, GAN example on pytorch tutorials uses stats=((0.5, 0.5, 0.5),(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)) as I do, so in this case I am just following the example and in that part do not do any improvisations. But it just does not work. Does anyone know how to fix it. Or should I try to create custom Dataset instead TensorImage

Answer (score 0):

It appeares that, problem was created by defining stat = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5),(0.5, 0.5, 0.5) outside Normalize(stat). It is vierd as Python does not restrict that. Is it problem of pytorch or the problem of google colab, does anyone know anything?
Also only way to clear the failure appeared to be termination of session from colab -> runtime -> manage sessions , othervise crush persists.
And I lost whole day figuring it out :/